# Slick.js breaking styling after loading a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I am working a basic HTML/CSS/JavaScript webpage, on the page is a section for teams. This section will have 4 teams with staff for each. Using Slick.js the user will select a flag for the related team and that will then load a slider for that team while hiding the previous slider. Each slider will load all the members for that team as a slide.

[image: what it should look like]

The picture above should give you a visual idea of what I'm looking to achieve. the small green boxes will be the flags and I'm pretty sure you can work out the rest. The slider will show a number of slides at once and you click left or right to display the next in the list.

The issue: When clicking on flags each slider is being replaced with the new one which is working however randomly and more often than not when clicking between the flags I will find the sliders stacked and not displaying correctly.

[image: broken :(]

Here is what I have... 
(HTML):

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      function initSlider(target) {
        $(target).slick({
          dots: false,
          infinite: true,
          speed: 300,
          autoplay: true,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          adaptiveHeight: true
        });
      }
    
      initSlider('.quote-1');
      initSlider('.quote-2');
      initSlider('.team-uk');
      initSlider('.team-uk-small');
    
      $('.team-flag').click(function(e){
        $('.team-flag').removeClass('active');
        $('.team-slider').addClass('hidden');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        $(target).removeClass('hidden');
        initSlider(target);
      });
    
      $('.team-flag-small').click(function(e){
        $('.team-flag-small').removeClass('active');
        $('.team-slider').addClass('hidden');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        $(target).removeClass('hidden');
        initSlider(target);
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h4>THE TEAM</h4>
        </div>          
    
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="team-slider team-uk" data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 3, "slidesToScroll": 1}'>
    
              <!-- Team Member Slide -->
              <div class="team-player col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <img class="center-block" src="/img/andy.png" />
                <p class="lead">Andy</p>
                <p>CTO</p>
                <div class="team-icon-group">
                  <a href="" class="team-social-btn"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                  <a href="" class="team-social-btn"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Team Member Slide end -->
    
              <!-- Repeated -->           
    
            </div>
    
            <div class="team-slider team-usa hidden" data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 3, "slidesToScroll": 1}'>
    
              <!-- Team Member Slide -->
              <div class="team-player col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <img class="center-block" src="/img/andy.png" />
                <p class="lead">Team America</p>
                <p>CTO</p>
                <div class="team-icon-group">
                  <a href="" class="team-social-btn"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                  <a href="" class="team-social-btn"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Team Member Slide end -->
    
              <!-- Repeated -->        
    
            </div>
    
            <div class="team-slider team-india hidden" data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 3, "slidesToScroll": 1}'>
    
              <!-- Team Member Slide -->
              <div class="team-player col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <img class="center-block" src="/img/andy.png" />
                <p class="lead">Team India</p>
                <p>CTO</p>
                <div class="team-icon-group">
                  <a href="" class="team-social-btn"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                  <a href="" class="team-social-btn"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Team Member Slide end -->
    
              <!-- Repeated -->      
    
            </div>
    
            <div class="team-slider team-hong-kong hidden" data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 3, "slidesToScroll": 1}'>
    
              <!-- Team Member Slide -->
              <div class="team-player col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <img class="center-block" src="/img/andy.png" />
                <p class="lead">Team Hong Kong</p>
                <p>CTO</p>
                <div class="team-icon-group">
                  <a href="" class="team-social-btn"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                  <a href="" class="team-social-btn"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Team Member Slide end -->           
    
                <!-- Repeated --> 
    
            </div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="col-md-12 team-flag-group">
            <img src="/img/web-assests/uk-flag.jpg" alt="UK Team" class="team-flag active" id="team-uk-btn" data-target=".team-uk" />
            <img src="/img/web-assests/usa-flag.jpg" alt="USA Team" class="team-flag" id="team-usa-btn" data-target=".team-usa"/>
            <img src="/img/web-assests/india-flag.jpg" alt="India Team" class="team-flag" id="team-india-btn" data-target=".team-india"/>
            <img src="/img/web-assests/hong-kong-flag.jpg" alt="Hong Kong Team" class="team-flag" id="team-hong-kong-btn" data-target=".team-hong-kong"/>
          </div>
    
      </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

At this stage I don't believe I have done anything wrong but completely open to correction as I wouldn't say I'm an expert at JavaScript so any help will be appreciated.

Edit: I forgot to mention that when the style doesn't load it does kick in after 4-5 seconds but obviously from a end users position this looks buggy.

Comment: Shouldn't you just be initializing your sliders just once, then just toggle they visible state after that? Or at least destroy them before you re-init them again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue has to do with hiding and showing your carousel. When you put the class `hidden` on your carousel it gets the style `display: none;` and then when you remove it Slick has a hard time setting the positions of the slides like when it first gets initialized. That's why all the slides become stacked vertically.

To fix this you should call `.slick('setPostion')` on the slider if it has already be initialized. You can tell if a slider has already been initialized if it has the class `.slick-initialized`.

Your code would then look something like this:

```
$('.team-flag').click(function(e) {
    $('.team-flag').removeClass('active');
    $('.team-slider').addClass('hidden');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $(target).removeClass('hidden');

    if ($(target).hasClass('slick-initialized'))
      $(target).slick('setPosition');
    else
      initSlider(target);
  });
```

This way you are also only initializing the slider only once.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/quuqzvp8/5/) for a demo of the working solution.