# SlickJS vertically aligned slides on load but on interaction with arrows fix the layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, slick.js

I have created a demo to show my problem. When you go to the contact section you will see all the slickJS slide stack vertically but as soon as you click on the arrow or slide the content or interact with any slide,  it fixes itself.
Problem appears only on load.

Here is the demo [codepen](https://codepen.io/xblack/pen/jOqRvBd)

```
$(".demo-slider").slick({  
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slideToScroll:1, 
  infinite: true,
  arrow:true
});
```

Comment: Similar issue: [Slick Slider not loading properly on an hidden div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61957408/slick-slider-not-loading-properly-on-an-hidden-div).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by triggering slick.js' refresh event when the contact tab is shown, like this:

```js
$(".demo-slider").slick({  
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slideToScroll:1, 
  infinite: true,
  arrow:true
});

$('#nav-contact-tab').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  $('.demo-slider').slick('refresh');
});
```

[You can see my fork in codepen](https://codepen.io/lucasreta/pen/gOrydjK?editors=1010).

Comment: I though so too. Since contact tab remain hidden, slick slider can't set the height of slick slides so I thought I would set the height on click on Contact tab but that didn't work.  from here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45801842/slick-js-breaking-styling-after-loading-a-slider

Comment: when I used click event instead of shown.bs.tab, it was getting refreshed but the layout was jumping from vertical to horizontal which wasn't happening in your solution.